# Read certificate from smart card which is currently inserted in reader

Tags: certificate, smartcard

I am trying to read certificate form smart card which is currently inserted in the reader to connect for secure session. 
In my application as of now when user1 insert his smart card to connect in secure session, application prompt to put pin, and session gets connected.
smart card details (name, provider) will be stored in config file (not pin).
user1 will not logoff machine but removes smart card. 
Now when user2 insert his smart card, application try to connect with the certificate from user1 smart card and prompt for pin. 
 I would like to distinguish certificate based on smart card inserted or read certificate form inserted smart card. Is their any properties or api which can be use.

Thanks,
DJ

Comment: Note : I am using java in my application.

Comment: What is the question? (Details like copying to config file are surely not important.) Surely any application MUST monitor, when the card it uses is removed, to maintain the correspondance of current card and user.

Comment: Surely the smartcarg will have a driver and a manual...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for looking in to this, I'll try to explain my problem again.

Comment: In my application when user insert smart card, application prompts to put pin/password.(During configuration user's admin has selected option not to prompt for pin again and again if certificate is available)  
card details like name,date will be stored in one of the config file.user finish his work and remove his card.
Now another user say user 2 put smart card, application prompts to provide card however this time application picking up old certificate so whenever user put his pin, it doesn't accept pin and keep prompting to provide correct pin. user2 might not aware about certificate

Comment: user2 might not aware application is not picking up his certificate so he will not choose his certificate ... this is problem  
So I would like to distinguish certificate based on inserted smart card .. so when user insert smart card, application should pickup  certificate only from smart card ... 
I wanted to know some way where I can check, selected certificate from inserted smart card or not .. 

So is there any API or properties which can be use to achieve this. thanks again. DJ

Comment: Why you do not compare the Common Name or serial number of the certificate of the last sucessful login with actual to know if smartcard has changed? And to exclude certificates from list presented by your app, why you can not filters, for example by certificate issuer?